# Easiest Way to Browse to Router Admin (PC Subnet Mask 255.255.254.0) Router 255.255.255.0

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, router

Don't ask how I got into this fix.  Just need to get out.  Can't access Router Admin page until both PC and Router are in the same address neighborhood.  How to do?

Comment: More information is required to provide a meaningful response - like what IP addresses are assigned to each device, and how the addresses are assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Your real issue comes into what the IP of the router and computer are. Those two subnet masks will work fine together if the IP of both devices are on the same network. (Let me know if you want subnetting explained.)

The most common gateway address for consumer devices is `192.168.1.1`. I would try entering `http://192.168.1.1' into your browser and see if you get a login page.

No login? No problem. Open command prompt and type `ipconfig` and press enter. You should see an IP address listed for your gateway for your ethernet adapter or your wireless adapter depending on how you are connected. Enter that address in the browser to see if you get a login page.

Still no luck? Maybe your computer is on a different network than your router. In this case, things can get tricky. First, check to see if there is a sticker or book that came with your router telling you the default address. Let's say the sticker says `192.168.1.1`. Run another `ipconfig` command from command prompt and see what it says for ipv4 address. In this case, since the computer has a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0, it can only talk to things on the routers network if it has an address in between '192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.254' if the ip address is not in that range, change it.

Lets say you do not have the routers ip address. Plug your computer in, make sure it is set to dhcp and hopefully, your router will give you an address on it's network. Once you are plugged in, the `ipconfig` command can be ran to verify the gateway and ip address are on the same subnet.

Worse case scenario, if none of that works, hard reset the router so it will obtain its known, default IP.

Comment: I've tried every step; I guess I may have missed something, or course.  The router IP is discoverable with the ASUS Device Discovery Utility: it is 192.168.1.2, subnet mask 255.255,.254.0.  The PC is IP 73.173.67.80 subnet mask 255.255.254.0.  I've disconnected the Modem from the configuration,leaving only the Router LAN Port Connected to PC ethernet port --- still could not rouse the router using 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.1.2.  Tried resetting the router using the 30/30/30 method, but I don't think that worked, as the Device Discovery utility still showed IP as 192.168.1.1.

Comment: That utility tells me I can't configure my router because it is on a different subnet mask.  Tried establishing a static IP on the PC within the correct subnet but have been unsuccessful.. Can I take the PC off internet, leaving just connected to router, and then make the PC static IP close to router?

Comment: Yes. Remove the modem completely for now. Connect an ethernet cable in between the two (comp and router). Give your machine a static address of the following: IP: 192.168.1.10, mask: 255.255.254.0, default gateway: leave blank for now. DNS: blank for now. You should now be able to hit the router. Be sure, when configuring the router, that DHCP is enabled. After you have configured that, flip the computers network settings back to dhcp, or (automatically obtain an ip address) and then plug the modem into the routers wan port. Should be good to go at that point.

Comment: Thanks for your interest.  Solved problem by FINALLY getting router to reset to factory settings.  Many internet theories on how to do this.  What worked for me was holding reset button while monitoring the power button --- it initially goes out, then slow flashes for a few seconds, but then goes to rapid flash.  When you see rapid flash, release reset button.  Everything is good now...